# [mapkit]Zoom in on the map, pin will move with the map

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotationview

Recently in the development of an application with a map, with the mapkit framework, after I set the coordinates, MKAnnotationView this view, pin will move with the map when zoom in on the map, pins and actual location a certain deviation phenomenon has taken place, and of course when zoom in to the largest position is correct, but I look at Google map is stationary pin location, if the map to zoom in on pins, offset, so that the user experience is very bad.

Thank you very much!

http://www.cocoachina.com/ask/questions/show/95208/mapkit%E5%9C%A8%E5%9C%B0%E5%9B%BE%E6%94%BE%E5%A4%A7%E7%BC%A9%E5%B0%8F%E7%9A%84%E6%97%B6%E5%80%99%E5%B0%8F%E5%9B%BE%E9%92%89%E4%BC%9A%E9%9A%8F%E7%9D%80%E5%9C%B0%E5%9B%BE%E7%A7%BB%E5%8A%A8

Comment: I don't understand your question, and I think a lot of people will have trouble with it. Can you try again. Maybe with pictures to show what is happening and what you want to happen.

Comment: Sorry,My english is so bad,Did you look up the web with I supplied url

Comment: I promise you that your English is better than my Chinese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason it looks like your pin is moving is that you are looking at the bottom of the pin. If you look at the center of the pin it is always over the same location. You will need to change the offset of your custom pin image. Check out this question and answer: [iPhone custom pin position issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319980/iphone-custom-pin-position-problem)

Comment: Thank you very much,it's trouble on centerOffet,solved
`annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(5.0f, -15.0f);`

Comment: I'm glad to hear your problem is solved. Now you need to "accept" this answer by ticking it.

Comment: I am first, I am sorry, I don‘t know what should I do to "accept"? Could you told me? Thank you!

Comment: I should click, Thank you very much!